# How to set item height equal to FlatList height in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a vertical flat list with paging enabled. I want to make each item covering the flat list height.

Comment: try adding styles in the component being returned by the function passed as `renderItem` props of flatList. You can use the `dimension` API to calculate width and height of the list.

Comment: show image or add your code for reference of what you want..

Comment: That doesn't work. For example Giving item height of 600 will not not perfect fit for a flatlist of height 600.

Comment: is it solved i got same issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the height of each rendered item to the window height

```
height : Dimensions.get('window').height
```

Comment: That doesn't work. For example Giving item height of 600 will not not perfect fit for a flatlist of height 600.

Answer (score 2):

Setting flexGrow:0 for the Flatlist solved it for me! Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a ScrollView Horizontal. For me fixed setting height: 100% for the items list.

[before fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MhVv.png)
[after fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0qvf.png)